# Activating/Deactivating buttons from config file C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, button, configuration

Let's say that my program have max 8 buttons and I should be able to switch them on/off (visible/hidden) according to my settings in configuration file.
My chosen buttons should be then visible in two rows (if more than 4) or one row (cnt<=4) on the form leaving no gap between them.(I mean when 1,2,3,4 are active they would be in the first row same 1,2,5,8 is active so the 5 will take place of the button 3 and 8 will take the 4th place)

```
<add key="butactive" value="1;3;4;8"/>
<add key="but1" value="START"/>
<add key="but2" value="END"/>
<add key="but3" value="PAUSE"/>
<add key="but4" value="RESET"/>
...
```

The program should be able to determine from "butactive" key which of those buttons will be visible and then change their Text property and add specific action which is also taken from config file.

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     radButton1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["but1"];
     radButton2.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["but2"];
     radButton3.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["but3"];
     radButton4.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["but4"];
     ...
     radButton1.Click += getAction(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["but1a"]);
     radButton2.Click += getAction(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["but2a"]);
     ...
 }
```

Any idea how to select needed buttons when the form loads and place them in desired positions?

Comment: Why do you need to determine 1,3,4,8 while you can manage the caption and function behind it in config file? I think you can manage to use sequence button and not the random one.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it there is really no need to specify buttons 1,4,3,8 etc. but just add only 5. The main idea was that there are 8 named buttons, 16 actions and I will choose which to use. It would be easier to add only the exact number of buttons I need and their actions plus add or write the whole list of actions somewhere in code comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) as a container for your buttons. If you size it correctly everything you need to do is set the visibility of the buttons and they will arrange themselves as you need:

```
radButton1.Visible = (bool)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["butactive1"];
radButton2.Visible = (boll)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["butactive2"];
...
```

As for the action, you can use the same event handler for all the buttons and execute whatever you need based on the button that was pressed and what action you have defined:

```
radButton1.Click += buttonClickHandler;
radButton2.Click += buttonClickHandler;

private void buttonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var action = getAction(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[button.Text + "a"];

    //Execute whatever you want here based on action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That piece of code you have there is not good, you are creating dependencies on config names with hard codded strings, that is not a good practice at all, if you can access Properties.Default I suggest you to go that way.

For the buttons position you can mess around with positions, for instance you can switch button 3 and 5 positions like this in windows forms:

```
radButton5.Position = radButton3.Position
```

But **that is not a good approach**, what I advice you is to cut that dependency in button numbers out, you can for instance create all buttons hidden and always show the first buttons, the method "getAction" will be a great help in that approach and its not to hard to implement the behavior.

A Scratch (pseudo code) of what you should do would be something like this:

```
 // Get the active buttons from configuration (eg var will be a list of the active buttons names)
 var activeButtons = getActiveButtons();
 var textBoxNumber = 0
 foreach(var button in activeButtons)
 {
    textBoxNumber++;
    TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("radButton" + textBoxNumber.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;

    if(tbx != null)
       tbx.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[button];
 }
```